# can I validate input on MTurk?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I've written a HIT on mturk asking people for domain suggestions. Is there any way to ensure that the domain has valid syntax at the time of entry or submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out you can embed an iframe within the HIT. This allowed me to embed a form which I could then validate in any way I pleased. It requires the worker to copy the result of the form into the HIT form.

Answer (score 0):

I think to do this the 'proper way' (i.e. no need to copy-paste) you'd need to use an [ExternalQuestion](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/2008-02-14/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html). This can be done via either the API (various languages) or the command-line client.